# replace last character in a line with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace the last character in a line with the same character plus a quotation mark `'`

This is the sed code

```
 sed "s/\([A-Za-z]\)$/\1'/g" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

but does not work. Where is the error?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure the last character on the line is one of `[A-Za-z]`? Does it work if you replace `[A-Za-z]` with `.`?

Comment: @emanuele , you wrote [a-zA-Z]$ but expect matching a dot??

Comment: sed "s/\(.\)$/\1'/g" file1.txt > file2.txt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
sed "s/\([a-zA-Z]\)\s*$/\1\'/" file
```

This will replace the last character in the line followed by none or many spaces.

HTH Chris

Comment: This works for lines that end in a letter possibly followed by white space. I'm glad the OP found his answer, but this is not what he asked for! +1 for the mind reading ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It seems pointless to replace a character with itself, so try this: for lines ending with a letter, add a quote to the end:

```
sed "/[a-zA-Z]$/s/$/'/"
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you ask for:

```
sed "s/\(.\)$/\1'/" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line only matches a line with a single character. Note that the `s` operation only takes effect if the *line* matches, not if only a subset of the line matches the regex.